# Discord.py Say Command Rich Embed

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Ok so I have a say command that works fine as is, however, I want to redo it to use a Rich Embed. My question is how would I go about doing that?

Here is my say command as is:

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def say(self, ctx, *, message):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send(message)
```

Anyone know how to make it put the message into a Rich Embed? I know how to form the actual Rich Embed, but not how to make it put the message into the Rich Embed. That's pretty much where I'm hung up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a bit of tweaking I found a way to make it work as an embed.

Here is what I managed to get working. It's not perfect but it does what I was trying to do anyway.

```
    @commands.command(name="say")
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
    async def Say(self, ctx, *, message):
        await ctx.message.delete()

        embed = discord.Embed(color=ctx.author.color, timestamp=ctx.message.created_at)

        embed.set_author(name="Announcement!", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

        embed.add_field(name=f"Sent by {ctx.message.author}", value=str(message))

        embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this and its better

```
@bot.command(aliases = ['embedsay'])
async def say(ctx, *, args):
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Test", description=f"{args}")
  await ctx.message.delete()
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```